# Pairing even and odd numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm studying for my C exam, and my professor said that my solution to the exercise isn't efficient enough. How can I make it more efficient?

Exercise: Write a program in which you initialize an array of N elements (N is a constant). In the program, generate and print a new array in which the elements from the first one are ranked according to parity (first even, then odd, they do not have to be in size.)

My solution was this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define N 10
int
main ()
{

int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int b[N];
int i, j, temp;
for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
{
  for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
            }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  b[i] = a[i];
  printf ("%d,", b[i]);
}

}
```

Comment: I think this question would work better on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), given that the code you posted is already working and functional, at some good level.

Comment: You could fill the destination array by putting the even numbers at the start, incrementing an index, and the odd numbers at the end whilst decrementing a different index for that.

Comment: Why are you reordering the elements already in a and then copy it to b? It would be more efficient when copying and reordering in one step. Loop over a when having an eben number, add it to the left of b, when finding an odd number add it to the right. Therefore you need two counter, one for the next free left Index, and one for the next free right.

Comment: It's not efficient enough because it implements an O(N^2) algorithm. This can be done in O(N) by either (a) making two passes across `a[]` and using a write pointer that is bumped with each element selected, or (b) using two indexes, stuffing all even values on the low side incrementing up, the odd values on the high side decrementing down. Btw, it is *considerably* more challenging to do this exercise without the second array (i.e. arrange by even/odd in-place).

Comment: An easy efficient solution would walk over the given array twice, the first time copying the even items into the second array, the second time copying the odd elements.  Your approach looks sorta like a bubble-sort, but it has a real issue in that it doesn't increment `i` once it swaps an even value forward...so it does a whole lot of churning.  If you eliminate the outer loop, initialize `i` to 0 and just increment `i` in the if-body in the inner loop, I think you'd have the in-place linear-time 1-pass solution.

Comment: Is 'parity' as simple as 'value of last bit'?  I thought it was the number of one-bits in the value — so both 1 and 2 have odd parity (a single one bit each), while 0 and 3 both have even parity (with 0 and 2 one bits respectively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is O(N**2) since you have two nested loops that each iterates O(N) times.

The complexity of most efficient algorithm is O(n). This is a simple stable partitioning algorithm:

```
int write_pos = 0;
/* copy only even: O(N) */
for (int i=0 ; i < N ; i++)
{
  if (a[i] % 2 == 0)
  {
     b[write_pos++] = a[i];
  }
}
/* copy only odd: O(N) */
similar to the above
```

Total complexity O(N)+O(N) = O(N).

I am using the additional memory (which was given in the question), but partitioning can also be done in place. In place partitioning runs in O(n), if it is acceptable to have unstable partitioning.

If the goal is to have O(1) additional memory and a stable partition (that retains relative order of elements), then runtime complexity becomes O(n log n). Such partitioning is performed recursively on half-sized arrays. The half-sized arrays are then merged by rotating the middle.